# How can I perform operations in JavaScript just like we do pipeline of operations in Java streams?

Tags: javascript, java

In Java 8 using streams when I chain methods one after the another the execution of operations are performed in pipelined manner.

Example:

```
List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);    
nums.stream().map(x->{
    x = x * x;
    System.out.println("map1="+x);
    return x;
}).map(x->{
    x = x * 3;
    System.out.println("map2="+x);
    return x;
}).forEach(x-> System.out.println("forEach="+x));
```

Output:-

```
map1=1
map2=3
forEach=3
map1=4
map2=12
forEach=12
map1=9
map2=27
forEach=27
map1=16
map2=48
forEach=48
map1=25
map2=75
forEach=75
map1=36
map2=108
forEach=108
```

But when I tried similarly in javascript.The result is different.As in javascript first operation gets completed and then second operation is performed.Example:-

```
var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6 ];
nums.map(x => {
  x = (x * x);
  console.log('map1='+x);
  return x;})
  .map(x => {
  x = x * 3;
  console.log('map2='+x);
  return x;})
  .forEach(x=> console.log('forEach='+x));
```

Output:-

```
 map1=1
 map1=4
 map1=9
 map1=16
 map1=25
 map1=36
 map2=3
 map2=12
 map2=27
 map2=48
 map2=75
 map2=108
 forEach=3
 forEach=12
 forEach=27
 forEach=48
 forEach=75
 forEach=108
```

Is there any way in JavaScript to make it performs operations in a pipeline manner, and I get output as in the Java program?

[This question ask only how to collect like in JavaScript but not how internal working changes for same type of methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408033/javascript-equivalents-for-java-streams-api).

Comment: do you want a native solution from JS or look for some library/helper class?

Comment: check out [Lazy.js](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/) sadly I didn't find it on a CDN to create a snippet here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript equivalents for Java Streams API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408033/javascript-equivalents-for-java-streams-api)

Comment: @AdityaGupta both questions are conceptually different.

Comment: Conceptually, what you asked for is a `stream` implementation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe later (or never) you can use the actual **experimental** [pipeline operator `|>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Pipeline_operator), which has the following syntax:

```
expression |> function
```

Your wanted result could be achieved by taking the functions as separate functions and iterate the stream array for each pipe.

**This works only in FF. From version 58: this feature is behind the `--enable-pipeline-operator` compile flag.**

```js
const
    a = x => { x = x * x; console.log("map1=" + x); return x; },
    b = x => { x = x * 3; console.log("map2=" + x); return x; },
    c = x => console.log("forEach=" + x)

var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

nums.forEach(v => v |> a |> b |> c);
```

The same with a pipe as function ([function composition enabling piping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Function_composition_enabling_piping)) with a closure over the wanted functions.

```js
const
    pipe = (...functions) => input => functions.reduce((acc, fn) => fn(acc), input),
    a = x => { x = x * x; console.log("map1=" + x); return x; },
    b = x => { x = x * 3; console.log("map2=" + x); return x; },
    c = x => console.log("forEach=" + x)

var nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    pipeline = pipe(a, b, c);

nums.forEach(pipeline);
```

Comment: All F# devs praise the pipe operator :D

Answer (score 12):

If you put each function operation into an array, you can iterate over that array with `reduce` and pass the last calculated value along in the accumulator until the end of the function array is reached:

```js
var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6 ];
var fns = [
  (x) => {
    x = x * x;
    console.log('map1=' + x);
    return x;
  },
  (x) => {
    x *= 3;
    console.log('map2=' + x);
    return x;
  },
  (x) => {
    console.log(x);
    return x;
  }
];

nums.forEach((num) => {
  fns.reduce((lastResult, fn) => fn(lastResult), num);
  // pass "num" as the initial value for "lastResult",
  // before the first function has been called
});
```

You can't use `nums.map` because `.map` will necessarily iterate through the whole input array before resolving to the mapped output array (after which the mapped output array will then have another `.map` called on it).

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent to Java's streams are JavaScript's [iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols). Iterator objects unfortunately don't have a `map` method ([yet](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers)), but you can easily write one yourself (and even [install it on the prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31232620/1048572) if you want method syntax).

```js
function* map(iterable, f) {
    for (var x of iterable)
        yield f(x);
}

var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
function square(x) {
  x = (x * x);
  console.log('map1='+x);
  return x;
}
function triple(x) {
  x = x * 3;
  console.log('map2='+x);
  return x;
}
for (const x of map(map(nums.values(), square), triple)) {
  console.log('forEach='+x);
}
```

Also notice that in functional programming, order doesn't matter for pure operations - you shouldn't need to rely on the execution order if you are using `map`.

Comment: Do NOT mutate the prototypes of any type you are not the developer of. If everyone went around mutating prototypes, any library could break any other libraries because they would override each others prototype mutations. https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/4146602

Comment: @Suppen agreed. You might use a polyfill from the iterator methods proposal though.

Answer (score 1):

Why re-invent from scratch when we have solutions. This functionality is present in  **lodash/RxJS/stream.js**.

Example snippet from lodash:

```
_.flow(
 _.assign(rows[0]),
 _.omit('blah')
)(foundUser);

// >> {"charData":[],"ok": 1}
```

However, javascript runs on single thread and so do these libraries. Java streams benefit from multi core systems(in case of parallel). There they can use multiple threads to use all available cores.

Comment: But what if I don't want to load one more library to my page load just for only this type of scenario?

Comment: Valid point! But, adding a library would be better than writing bloated code. You could get rid of boilerplate code using the libraries.

Comment: We could also opposed the fact that unlike Java, the default runtime Javascript don't hae that much of stuff, that's why we need libraries so fast in JS.

Comment: You are still using libraries in the Java case, the difference is that they are provided by Oracle

Comment: @Caleth No, the difference is that in Java the library doesn't bloat your application.

Comment: To sum up, code maintanence and code abstraction should be a developer's focus. Adding a small minified script does more good than than harm.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use libraries like RxJS. This gives you more control over the kind of processing, should it be sequential, parallel or whatsoever.

Here is an example, which is close to what you expect:

```
const source = Rx.Observable.from([{name: 'Joe', age: 30}, {name: 'Frank', age: 20},{name: 'Ryan', age: 50}]);
const example = source.map(person => {
  console.log("Mapping1" + person.name)
  return person.name
});
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

outputs:

```
"Mapping1Joe"
"Joe"
"Mapping1Frank"
"Frank"
"Mapping1Ryan"
"Ryan"
```

Comment: The java code example at the question never calls `.paralel()`, and thus NEVER executes on multiple threads. Threads don't have anything to do with the issue. streams in Java work almost the same to iterators, 1 item from the start to the source at a time.  The OP also requested a JavaScript code that does the same as his Java code, not a Java code that does the same as his JavaScript code

Comment: Okay, then I may had a wrong expectation from the Java internals, sorry for that. But can you explain your second point? I did provide the Javascript code and not Java code, so I don't get what you mean.

Comment: I think I made a mistake when I said my second point, I think I missed the word "like" in the paragraph above it ( based on the time of my comment, it seems like I made the comment when I was traveling with the subway and using the SE app at the moment I made it). Sorry for wasting your time with the second point. I did some research and it seems like the "Rx.Observable" library you recommend works almost the same as java streams for the simple cases, so if you can edit your post to remove this, I can actually retract my downvote

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation. I removed the part about Java and the misleadings ”like" part.

Answer (score 0):

The JS code you're using here doesn't have any concept of lazy evaluation - the return value of .map() is already an array value that must have been completely evaluated before its own .map() method can be executed. This isn't an implementation detail of how the interpreter operates, but part of the language definition. (Meanwhile, the Java code's Collection.stream() method returns a Stream object whose contents aren't evaluated yet.)

JavaScript does have the asynchronous/delayed evaluation functionality you want in the form of the **Promise** object.

The following code would do something like what you want:

```
var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6 ];
nums.map(async function(x) {
  x = (x * x);
  console.log('map1='+x);
  return x;
}).map(async function(x) {
  x = await x;
  x = x * 3;
  console.log('map2='+x);
  return x;
}).forEach(async function(x) {
  x = await x;
  console.log('forEach='+x);
});
```

Now, in practice this will still print the output in the same order as before, because the Promise resolves immediately. However, this time the evaluation of the map function is indeed "lazy" and could in principle occur in any order. To actually test this, we can introduce a delay in the calculation, using an asynchronous sleep() function (from [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)):

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6 ];
nums.map(async function(x) {
  x = (x * x);
  await sleep(1); // 1ms delay
  console.log('map1='+x);
  return x;
}).map(async function(x) {
  x = await x;
  x = x * 3;
  console.log('map2='+x);
  return x;
}).forEach(async function(x) {
  x = await x;
  console.log('forEach='+x);
});
```

Output:

```
map1=1
map2=3
forEach=3
map1=4
map2=12
forEach=12
map1=9
map2=27
forEach=27
map1=16
map2=48
forEach=48
map1=25
map2=75
forEach=75
map1=36
map2=108
forEach=108
```

Answer (score -2):

You kinda get the same output, as in the relative values of the sequence of `map1`, `map2` and `forEach` values are the same.

The difference in order that you're seeing shows the underlying difference between the machine models of the JVM and the JavaScript runtime engine.

JVMs are threaded.  JavaScript is not.  That means, that your sequence steps in Java can run immediately after the critical number of map operations have occurred.

In JavaScript, the next step is put at the bottom of the execute stack, and every operation at the top must first be executed before getting to the next items.

As you can see, the methods are functionally equivalent, but have different mechanics.

Comment: But in java also it is running with single thread and similarly operations in javascript are performed by one thread.

Comment: He never used .parallel (), his stream is therefore just running on 1 thread. Just explanation is invalid