# Create variable of arguments type

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make middleware function lets call it debug, which should take some parameters, log them and pass to the next function:

```js
const debug = (...args) => {
 console.log(...args)
 return args // will return array, not argument type variable
}

const compose = (...fns) => (...arg) => (
  fns.slice().reverse().reduce(
    (acc, fn) => !acc ? fn(...arg) : fn(acc), null
  )
)

const f = x => x * x

const g = (a, b) => a + b

const makeMagic = compose(
  f,
  g,
  debug
)

makeMagic(1, 2)
```

If I remove debug from composition everything works as expected, as soon as I place it at end, it breaks. Because it takes arguments but returns array.

I tried to rewrite `debug` this way:

```js
function debug() {
  console.info(arguments)
  return arguments
}
```

But no way it fails.

Comment: What should `return args` return when `debug` is called with multiple arguments?

Comment: maybe this question helps a bit for taking an array: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54568053/1447675

Comment: @Mark Meyer it should return same amount of args.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function **always** has only a single result value. You can't write a function that accepts multiple arguments and "returns" multiple values without some kind of container around them (like an array), it's just not a feature JavaScript has (nor do most other programming languages).

You can make `debug` a pure pass-through for a *single* argument, but not multiple. So for instance, you could make this work:

```
const result = debug(makeMagic(1, 2))
```

...where `result` would be the value `makeMagic` returned (after `debug` logs it), but you can't include it in the composed `makeMagic` the way you're trying to.

To have `debug` (or any other function) in the middle of a chain with your `compose`, you'd have to use a convention with it and all `compose`able functions about how they return multiple values, probably by having them all return an array. That also helps with the fact taht right now, your `compose` function has what I assume is a bug: It uses `...args` any time a previous function returned a *falsy* value (`0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, or `false`), where I'm fairly sure you meant to do that only on the first call.

Here's a version of `compose` that expects composable functions, which are functions that return an array of their results:

```js
const debug = (...args) => {
    console.log(...args);
    return args;
};

const compose = (...fns) => (...args) => (
    fns.slice().reverse().reduce(
        (acc, fn) => fn(...(acc || args)),
        null
    )
);

const f = x => [x * x];

const g = (a, b) => [a + b];

const makeMagic = compose(
    f,
    g,
    debug
);

const result = makeMagic(1, 2);
console.log(result);
```